# Horizontal plane detection limitations?

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm trying to build an ARKit based app which requires detection of roads and placing virtual content 30 feet away from the camera. However horizontal plane detection is stopping to add anchors after about 10 feet. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    guard let usdzEntity = usdzEntity else { return }
    let camera = frame.camera
    let transform = camera.transform
    if let rayCast = arView.scene.raycast(from: transform.translation, to: usdzEntity.transform.translation, query: .nearest, mask: .default, relativeTo: nil).first {
        print(rayCast.distance)
    }
}
```

look at this, hope this can give you some help